# How should main.js and main.css be used in the skeleton portlet project generated by the Liferay 6.0.6 plugin SDK?

Tags: javascript, css, liferay, liferay-6

I'm reluctant to put portlet-specific JS or CSS in them unless `<portlet:namespace />` works in them as well.  Is it good practice to just hope that the function/variable names or class names I choose to use are unique enough?

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to hope for uniqueness anytime!? :-)

Comment: I thought so, too.  But then, of what use are main.js and main.css then?

Comment: Well even if you do have duplicate IDs or Classes in your CSS & code then when you deploy your portlet, you can use it's Look & Feel to change the CSS just for your portlet.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use the Portlet ID in your CSS files as prefix so something like:

```
#webform_WAR_webformportlet_somedivid { color: black; }
```

It won't look pretty, but it should be Unique as you're going to get as there shouldn't be any other portlets with the same name in the same WAR file.

Maybe someone else has a better idea?!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's OK to hard-code the portlet ID like that.

Comment: That's what the portlet ID will be though when you deploy it if it's not instantiable. So it's hard coded by it's nature. If it is instantiable then you can add the full ID to front.